Unable start Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
System:
Ubuntu 24.04

The last operation before the problem:
sudo apt install fuse

sudo apt remove fuse

The detail phenomenon:

nautilus disappeared
Unable to access "/home/xxx" before "reboot".(Something about disk, "disk manager" perhaps will start while double clicking the "folder Home")
The Desktop is normal before "reboot".
Unable to start gnome after "reboot".
Some strange outputs can be seen on the screen as below.


...


[ OK ] ...


[ OK ] Started gdm. service - GNOME Display Manager.


Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02


nvidia _ uvm: module uses symbols nvUvmInterfaceDisableAccessCntr from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.


iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
kauditd _ printk _ skb: 147 callbacks suppressed


You have a failed or failing hard drive. BTW I do not see anything in your question that would need to install the fuse File System support to fix it.

Do you mean that you do not have a desktop?

@DavidDE It's very strange, because I have never done anything about the hard drives. My computer is dual system, And another system win11 just works well. All the problem happens just after my uninstalling the fuse, so I wanna know if the fuse affect all these dives or if there exists other reasons. I don't know how to debug it. Could you give me a direction? Thanks

@amar I have a desktop but can not start it recently.  I have tried to reinstall the desktop but saw nothing happened, so I think these problem have little to do with the desktop itself. Maybe you can give me some advice to futher debug. Thanks

can you use ALT+F2 and log in to tty?

@amar Do you mean CTRL+ALT+F2. If so , I can log into it.

ok, Run df -h see if any partition is nearly full.
